# Angular + Ionic Post request getting 404 not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-post, ionic-framework

I have searched for the reason behind this error for the last couple hours unable to solve it. Hopefully someone has experienced the same issue and is able to help with a remedy.

I am using Ionic and Angular to create a simple application. I am running locally using Ionics **ionic serve** command to set up a simple server.

I have a simple index.html page that is as follows:

```
...
<body data-ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced">
        <h1 class="title ">Hello World!</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
        <h1>Some Content</h1>
    </ion-content>
</body>
...
```

and an app.js file that has been iterated numerous times and tried various online tutorials to end up with:

```
var App = angular.module("App", ["ionic"]);

App.controller("AppCtrl", ["$scope", "$http" , AppCtrl]);

    function AppCtrl($scope, $http) {

        $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        var request = $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://localhost:8100/php/login.php',
            data: { "cat" : "henry" },
            headers : {"Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("login.php failed");
        });
    };
```

**My problem:** is that I am getting "404 Not Found" error on my post requests. However, when I change to a get request, it seems to echo back the PHP file just fine. Its a simple echo "Hello World!" php file.

At this point, any helpful information would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Which browser are you working on? Did you try IE, Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: Have you made sure your server handle POST requests against `/php/login.php`?

Comment: I have tried Chrome, Mozzila and IE and all reply with "login.php failed" which is the result of an error on my http request.

Comment: Any idea how to make the "ionic serve" server handle POST requests. I tried adding headers in the php file to allow for CORS

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar issue and I this site helped me to understand my problem:
http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/

> By default:
>
> **jQuery** transmits data using Content-Type:
>   x-www-form-urlencoded.
>   **AngularJS** transmits data using Content-Type:
>   application/json.
>
> Which unfortunately some Web server languages, notably PHP, do not
>   unserialize natively.

**My solution was:**
In my .PHP I just did a JSON_DECODE in my content

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);